# Indenting subitems in QGIS Composer legend?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

My legend looks like this:

[image]

I would like the items under "Roads & Trails" to be indented to the right.
Likewise for the items under "Streams".

The spacing controls don't affect this. I could add spaces/tabs to the test, but the symbol would still be left-justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation of groups and subgroups in legends has been [introduced in QGIS 3.22](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html#feature-indentation-of-legend-groups-and-subgroups):

[image]

You can adjust the amount of indentation in the "Spacing" section of the Legend Item Properties:

[image]

Comment: thanks - a welcome improvement

Answer (score 3):

I too have struggled with this in the past, but my work around was to copy the legend, remove the items to be indented from the original one, and remove the title and top 3 items from the new one, then just move it to the required position manually.  You may have to remove the background and border from both legends, then draw a new one with the rectangle tool.

Not ideal, but at least you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but I guess it's the best we have for now.