# Indenting legend items in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend

My map legend looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to indent the circled items farther to the right but can't find any settings to adjust this. Using the item properties I know how to offset the label portion, but not the patch.

This is pretty much the same question I asked as [Indenting subitems in QGIS Composer legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/279707), but now trying to do this with ArcMap instead of QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

So, the way that I best know how to do this requires some manual work, but will return the results you are looking for.

Create the legend like normal. When it is created, right click on the legend and convert it to graphics. With the legend being converted to graphics, you can then ungroup everything and move the items you are focusing on. An easy way to align the indentation for these items is to click on the ruler on the top of the layout page and set it as a guide. Once done, you can then group everything in the legend back together to form one complete legend.

Again, this method is manually intensive but sometimes working like this on legends produces better looking results.

Comment: Please make clear that converting to graphics will make break the connection to the data, so if new layers are added, the legend will have to be recreated.